# Carousel slider autoplay after its loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using twitters bootstrap and carousel, but I loaded slider with ajax, and autoplay doesn't work... It works if it is not loaded by ajax...
Some solution??

My code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to tell, but you need to run

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
});
```

after you load the carousel into the DOM.

So

```
$.ajax({
    /* */
    complete: function(){
    /*load carousel*/
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000
    });
});
```